# Group chat - How to populate a table view with only the chat rooms a user is involved in?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a group chat app, and so far I have the app setup (from a tutorial) so that any user can create a room, and all of those rooms show up in a central list, which is the same for all users. Now I need to alter this so that users only see rooms that they created, or have been added to (just like any messaging app like iMessage).

This is how a room is created and appended to the `Room` object (and uploaded to Firebase):

```
var rooms: [Room] = []

// Create new room
@IBAction func createRoom(_ sender: Any) {
    if let name = newRoomTextField?.text {
        let newRoomRef = roomRef.childByAutoId()
        let roomItem = [
            "name": name
        ]
        newRoomRef.setValue(roomItem)
    }
}

private func observeRooms() {
    // Observe method to listen for new channels being written to Firebase
    roomRefHandle = roomRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        let roomData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let id = snapshot.key
        if let name = roomData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 {
            self.rooms.append(Room(id: id, name: name))
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print("Error! Could not decode channel data")
        }
    })
}
```

Room object:

```
internal class Room {
    internal let id: String
    internal let name: String

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Currently the table view of rooms is populated with `cell.textLabel?.text = rooms[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name` (`cellForRow` method), and `return rooms.count` (`numberOfRows` method), thus returning all of the rooms in the app, not specific to the user.

This is where I'm not sure how to proceed: I'm guessing I'll add an array "participants: [String]" to my Room object (in addition to "id" and "name"), then in `observeRooms` when I `self.rooms.append(Room(id: id, name: name))`, I'll also append the user's id to "participants"? Then populate the table view with only the rooms that the current user's id is a participant in?

Is this the right approach?

Thanks for any help/guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right approach, you basically have 2 choices :

- Store a `participants` array into each room, which allow you to query rooms where this array contains our current `userId`.
- Store a `rooms` array on each user, allowing to query rooms directly from this data.

The first approach seems to make more sense in case you'd like to also display a list of participants, though the query may take longer to execute than the second approach for many rooms * many participants.

You could also use both approach at the same time to have both your functionality and a faster query time for the user rooms.

Comment: Thanks! I also want to have the users (avatars) of a room displayed in the navigation bar (like in iMessage group chats) so maybe the first option will be the way to go. In terms of the way `cellForRow` will look, how will I narrow down the rooms to display to only those that the user is a participant in? I think that's where the confusion kicks in for me.

Comment: `cellForRow` is just the implementation of how the cell will look. The actual filtering must be done on your `self.rooms` array, manually or using a predicate.